# Using Throttle-Debounce with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, throttling

I'm using `deviceorientation` on a mobile site, but I don't want to capture every movement. I just want 1 per second, so I'm trying to use the throttle-debounce plugin.

My original working code looked like this...

```
window.addEventListener(
  'deviceorientation', 
  function (event) {
    tilt([event.alpha, event.beta, event.gamma]);
  }, 
  true);
```

...but when I add the throttle like so...

```
window.addEventListener(
 'deviceorientation', 
 $.throttle(
   1000, 
   function (event){
     tilt([event.alpha, event.beta, event.gamma]);
   }), 
 true);
```

... I get a...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'throttle'
```

I'm guessing I've gotten the syntax wrong, but I've tried a couple of variations and I can't quite get it. Help?

If anyone has a better way to do the same without a plugin that would be just as good :)

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded? If it is not, then the `$.throttle()` method is not available because it is not created under the jQuery alias of `$`—it is instead created as `Cowboy.throttle()`. I have worked with listening to `deviceorientation` and this worked perfectly fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

- no need jquery for simple debounce
- here a simple example of in vanilla purejs debounced function

```js
let timeoutId;
window.addEventListener(
  'deviceorientation', 
  function () {
     // you clear your time out each event
     clearTimeout(timeoutId)
     // if no event during 1s, then run your function
     timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
       // perform function after delay
     }, 1000)
  };
```